# Posting datetime from flutter to mysql database

Tags: mysql, flutter, date, synchronization

I have a flutter application that stores data offline and syncs to a mysql database when there is connectivity. All other fields are working fine except the date field. In my sqlite on the flutter application I am storing the date as DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch and my code for posting the data to mysql is as follows:-

```
var response= await htpp.post(
      Uri.parse('http://192.168.1.101:8080/api/receipts'),
          headers:  {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
          encoding: Encoding.getByName('utf-8'),
          body:jsonEncode({
          "contact_id":clientList[i].id.toString(),
          "user_id":clientList[i].userId.toString(),
          "service_name":clientList[i].service_name,
          "account_no":clientList[i].account_no,
          "amount":clientList[i].amount,
         // "is_sync":contactList[i].is_sync,
          //"created_at":clientList[i].createdAt,
            "created_at":  
DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(clientList[i].createdAt).toIso8601String(),
          }));
```

No matter the datatypes that I put on the mysql database I still find the date field empty. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I dont see anything wrong with that code. A couple things though:
- htpp is a typo? it should be http
- toIso8601String() returns a formatted date string. Don't you want the millisecondssinceepoch in your database? Thats way easier to handle
- are you sure that your database accepts text for that field and that it works?
- if nothing of the above helps can you post the important bit of the api?

Comment: Here is the post api :-     @PostMapping("/receipts")
    public ResponseEntity<Receipt> createReceipt(@RequestBody Receipt receipt){
        try {
            Receipt _receipt=receiptRepository
                    .save(new Receipt(receipt.getId(),receipt.getService_name(),receipt.getAccount_no(),receipt.getAmount(), receipt.getCreatedAt()));
            return new ResponseEntity<>(_receipt,HttpStatus.CREATED);

        }catch (Exception e){
            return new ResponseEntity<>(null,HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }

Comment: I am sure it has to do with encoding datetimes because that is the only field that is not getting posted. Am sure our answer will come from that angle.

Comment: Can you post the Receipt Class as well? Also, please edit your post and put the code into a codeblock instead of a comment! Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I will be posting it shortly.

Comment: public class Receipt {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    private String service_name;   
    private String account_no;
    private String amount;
    private Date createdAt;
    public Receipt() {   
    }